# I downloaded a PPA and now what?

Tags: apt, ppa

I downloaded a PPA successfully (I think) and now I what to run the program. I have now idea how to. I am new to Ubuntu. Here is the PPA I downloaded: `ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases`.

Then in terminal I ran the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then the instruction say *Now you're ready to install your program* but end there. What do I do next?

Thanks

Comment: The question is, what was your motivation to add the PPA? Was it to install the latest release of handbrake? Then you should enter `sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk`.

Comment: yes it was. Thanks. I just need the line of code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add that repository in your repository list.

You can do that by opening Terminal (or press Ctrl+Alt+T) then copy theese lines:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
```

You should now press Enter when terminal asks you if you want to add it.
Then if you wanted to install Handbreak type in next lines:

```
sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk
```

Answer (score 1):

> What do i do next?

You visit Ubuntu Software Center (USC) and search your software by name. USC has a section where you can browse contents of a PPA. See the left hand side for a list of installed PPA's (it starts with Adobe Flash in the image):

[image]

Mosttimes the place where you find the PPA is a website and then it probably also has instruction for the installation of software. In this case it would be:

```
sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk
```

if you want to install handbrake.

(credits to mad-mike for the command ;) )